# Is Database Backup Time = Restore Time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, backup, restore

I have a SQL Server Database with 10 GB size. When I performed a backup, it took almost 3-4 minutes. When I tried to restore, it took almost the same 3-4 minutes.

Does this mean backup and restore times of a SQL Server database are always equal, or can they differ?

Kindly suggest and point me the logic behind.

Comment: Was it a full backup?

Comment: I use the time for a backup to be a rough estimate of restore time, but it's not guaranteed.  For example, I'm usually backing up *all* my servers at around the same time, so my backups *tend* to be slower than restores.

Comment: I wouldn't even take backup as a rough estimate for restore. So many things can impact this (striping, disk types, backup settings, backup type, instant file init on/off, number of tran log changes, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference:

- [SQLskills SQL101: Why is restore slower than backup](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sqlskills-sql101-why-is-restore-slower-than-backup/)
- [Backup Time vs Restore Time](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1517321-391-1.aspx)
- [How long will this sql server restore take?](https://johnsterrett.com/2011/08/29/how-long-will-this-sql-server-restore-take/)

> Does this mean backup and restore times of a SQL Server database are
>   always equal, or can they differ?

They are not equal and yes they can (and most likely always) differ.

> Kindly suggest and point me the logic behind.

If you read the article from SQLSKills Paul Randal gave high level steps performed during a backup and restore. Which should explain why timing for these two operations are not same.

Answer (score 3):

This was a mere co-incidence. Both backup and restore are 2 different tasks which depend on various factors.

Answer (score 1):

10GB is fairly small. I've backed up and restored databases into the hundreds of gigabytes and I've seen big differences in backup speeds among different databases on the same server and between backing up a database and restoring it to another server.

Comment: Yes , I need to read more and more on this. Thanks much